# Компилятор не читает set в map

Tags: c++, коллекции, контейнеры, set

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
#define ll long long

using namespace std;

int main(){
    string s, res = "";
    map<char,set<char>> m;
    for (ll i = 1; i < s.size() - 1; i ++)
    {
        m[s[i - 1]].insert (s[i]);
        m[s[i]].insert (s[i - 1]);
        m[s[i]].insert (s[i + 1]);
        m[s[i + 1]].insert (s[i]);
    }

    for (char i = 'a'; i <= 'z'; i ++)
    {
        res += m[i][0];}
    }
}
```

Компилятор не читает `set` в `map` и выводит такую ошибку:

```
no match for operator[] (operand types are std::map<char, std::set<char> > and std::pair<const char, std::set<char> >)
```

Я попробовал и так:

```
res += m[i] -> begin();
```

Все равно не читает

Comment: `#define ll long long` можно же заменить на `typedef long long ll;`

Comment: @ДанилПерелыгин это не основной код

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну нет у `set` обращения по индексу (`[]`). Так что:

```
res += *m[i].begin();
```

Сами посмотрите, что у вас:

```
res += m[i] -> begin();
```

`m[i]` - это тип значения `map`, то бишь `set`. **Не указатель!** Поэтому надо использовать точку, а не `->`. Далее, вы получаете *итератор*, а не значение, и его надо разыменовать, чтоб добраться до значения, на которое он указывает.

P.S. Да, и уберите лишнюю фигурную скобку после `res += m[i][0];}` - чтоб потом еще один вопрос не писать...

P.P.S. А что вы подразумеваете под "Компилятор не читает"? Он может не читать исходный файл, но никакой `set` **компилятор** не читает.

Comment: а ещё я бы добавил, что сет для этой задачи не нужен. Если это полный код конечно.

Comment: @pavel Я даже не пытался вникнуть, что он там делает... Глянул только, что как-то неэффективно - при каждой итерации повторять уже сделанное, но просто не стал даже разбираться...

Comment: @Harry для задачи можно даже за n^2 решать

Comment: @pavel  это не полный код

Comment: Я к `insert`'ам это говорил. Например, первый на следующем шаге делает то же, что третий на предыдущем, второй и четвертый тоже...

Comment: @Harry спасибо, изменил